# PDF JS Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a HTML project. But my main aim is to display the pdf's on my site so that users can't save or download them is this possible using (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) viewer? If so how can i do it because i'm trying to output a lot of pdfs and this just seems impossible to do looking at the code.

Comment: if you have acrobat distiller then you can set options to prevent the file from being saved.

Comment: In order to show something on someone's screen you have to send it to them. And when you, they will be able to save it.

Comment: PDF.js can be optimized to download only portion of PDF data if HTTP range requests are enabled on the server. See disableAutoFetch and disableStream at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L92 (notice that Safari might have defect in XHR to handle range requests)

Comment: Also see [PDFDataRangeTransport](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L406) -- you can implement your own transport to transmit PDF data to make it more optimized for your requirement, you can e.g. transmit data over websockets or webrtc channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to display native pdfs to the user without allowing them to download them. By the nature of http, they will have had to download the pdf data in order for them to be displayed.

However, you could take snapshots of the pdf on the server, and display these to the user as pngs.

There are a [number of libraries](https://github.com/mooz/node-pdf-image) that will allow you to convert the first page of a pdf to an image, I suggest you start by trying to implement one of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Ill start looking at converting my first page to image's which will work and be the best solution for this project. Kvisoft FlipBook Maker can this be a possible solution when publishing it gives me different formats to publish.

Comment: When people suggest server side solutions, they have to disclose that files server operates on must be trusted -- any complex libraries such as ImageMagick potentially can be exploited making server data exposure/loss possible.

Comment: @async5 if I had to state that any server side tool I recommend could have vulnerabilities my posts would be incredibly repetitive. All libraries have their potential problems, it is up to the user to weigh up the pros and cons of each.